# how do I autoplay music when my app reloads

Tags: qt, qml, qtmultimedia

I'm making a game and I want the theme soundtrack to be autoplayed and to keep on looping no matter what is the viewed page/stack status...etc how do I do this? I already have:

```
App {
    onInitTheme: {
        Theme.navigationBar.titleColor = "transparent"
        Theme.navigationBar.height = 0
        nativeUtils.preferredScreenOrientation = NativeUtils.ScreenOrientationPortrait
    }

StackView {
    id: stack
    initialItem: mainView
    anchors.fill: parent
}
Component{
    id: mainView             //first scene
    Rectangle{
        id: canvas
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"
        Image {
            id: continueOW
            source: "../assets/continueWOSigning.svg"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: stack.push(playarea)
            }
        }
    }

    Component{
        id: playarea             //second scene
        Rectangle{
            id: playfield
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "black"
            Image {
                id: go_back
                source: "../assets/go_back.svg"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                MouseArea{
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: stack.push(mainView)
                }
            }
        }
    }


  }
}
```

I know I should be using something like this:

```
        Audio{
            id: win
            source: "../android/assets/win.wav"
        }
```

But where do I put it so it's visible to all scenes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `Audio` object lives as long as the `App` object lives, you can simply make it a direct child of the `App`.

Here is an example:

```
App {
    onInitTheme: {
        Theme.navigationBar.titleColor = "transparent"
        Theme.navigationBar.height = 0
        nativeUtils.preferredScreenOrientation = NativeUtils.ScreenOrientationPortrait
    }

//YOU OTHER CODES

    Audio{
        source: "../android/assets/win.wav"
        autoPlay: true
        loops : Audio.Infinite
    }
}
```

- By setting [autoPlay](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-audio.html#autoPlay-prop) to `true`, `autoLoad` would be overwritten to `true` as well.
- You are loading your `.wav` file from the assets directory. You could also make the same file available in the `.qrc`.

Comment: but the audio keeps on playing in the background whenever I exit from the game View and I can only stop it if I fully exited the game, are there any signals to control this? Can I pause the audio if the game isn't present?